# Header and Footer Navigation wrong links

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I've got a custom Storefront Controller which basically handles a Form. The Form i build is working without a problem, but the Links genereated for the header and footer are wrong.

This is the function where I render the Page:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/Widerrufsformular", name="frontend.rmaForm", defaults={"XmlHttpRequest": true, "csrf_protected": true}, methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function showRmaForm(Request $request, SalesChannelContext $context): Response
    {
        return $this->render('@MyStorefrontTheme/storefront/page/RmaForm/index.html.twig', [
            'page'           => $this->pageLoader->load($request, $context),
        ]);
    }
```

I dont know where the problem is comming from. The prblem seems to be in the following line:

```
'page'           => $this->pageLoader->load($request, $context),
```

Without this line there is no header and footer rendered on the page. With the line there is the header and footer but with the wrong links.

The Template I am using to render the Storefront has nothing in it (for Testing purpose) but the following line:

```
{% sw_extends '@MyStorefrontTheme/storefront/page/content/index.html.twig' %}
```

I have tried to extend from another Template like the Shopware base.html.twig:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/base.html.twig' %}
```

I also checked that the context is passed correct.
I checked that the Template path is correct and also tried using Templates from my theme in case they got changed.
I have cleared the cache and checked the JavaScript/CSS if there might be some problems but it is all fine.